# KVO message was received but not handled issues - SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift

All,

I have a working KVO request. I have an location class and a view controller. when the button is pressed on the view controller, it runs the location class to get the GEOLOCATION. and then it triggers a KVO and the view controller picks up the changes and then they go onto a label in the View Controller.

I am getting this error :

```
 An -observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: message was received but not handled.
```

Here is my code : 
In the locationManager class :

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

        let location = locations.last as! CLLocation

        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, e) -> Void in
            if let error = e {
                println("Error:  (e.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                let placemark = placemarks.last as! CLPlacemark
                self.LocationString = "\(placemark.subLocality), \(placemark.locality)"
                self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "LocationString", options: .New, context: nil)
                self.LocationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            }
        })
```

In my View Controller :

```
  override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject: AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {


    }
```

Comment: Have you tried just printing something inside observeValueForKeyPath?

Comment: yep i have tried println(change) and i still get the error

Comment: I dont understanding why do you have to use KVO like you do. Get rid of Swift value observers and declare LocationString as follow `var LocationString : String = ""{ didSet{ // handle change here }}`

Answer (score -1):

Just like apple Document "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-c" said,you need remove the observer in **deinit**

```
deinit{
self.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: , context:);
}
```